# Query Azure database using API

Tags: rest, azure, api, azure-tablequery

I host my database on Azure.  I would like to search data on the table in that database.  I am trying to use B4I and the tech help their said I need to use REST API's.  I am pretty sure I need to use ODATA.  I have the auth token but I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL, something on a VM, Cosmos DB or Table storage? The access options will vary depending on what service you are using. ex. Cosmos DB uses API as it's primary method of access whereas you would need a layer on top of Azure SQL to accomplish this.

Comment: I believe I am using Azure SQL, what would I need to use to query the tables?

Answer (score 0):

In order to query Azure SQL with an API you need to add a layer between it and the destination. As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830122/how-to-expose-azure-sql-server-database-using-odata), OData is a specification that can be implemented fairly easily as there are plenty of libraries that will take care of the bulk of the code for you.

As far as where to host the API, you have several options within Azure. The most common being [App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/), [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/), and [Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/).